# No keyword with name error

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to automation and I've been doing some training on PyCharm.

I have just separated out my script into a resource file to clean it up as per the Udemy course I am using. When I try and run the script however I get the following error message:

> No keyword with name 'Common.Start Test' found.

This keyword is 100% in my Common Resource file and the directory path and naming is all correct as PyCharm is auto-correcting these fields when typing them and hovering over them shows them to be correct?! What is wrong with it, why won't it find the keywords?

**Script**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  This is basic info about the suite
Resource    /Resources/Common.Robot
Resource    /Resources/Google.Robot
```

***Variables***

```
*** Test Cases ***
Kem getting to grips with this stuff
    [Documentation]  Basic test info
    [Tags]  Smoketest

    Common.Start Test
    Amazon.Searching Amazon
    Common.End Test
```

**Common Resource File**

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** Keywords ***

Start Test
    Open browser     about:blank    Chrome

End Test
    Close browser
```

Comment: is everything separate files ?

Comment: `Resource    ./Resources/Common.Robot`

Comment: Try adding a dot infront of the path

Comment: PyCharm is mostly an IDE for Python. If I remember correctly from a year or so ago, you have to use additional plugins in your PyCharm o be able to work in RF. If this is still true, what plugin do you use? Is it set up correctly? When you put keywords in one file with your test case, is it recognised or not? What is your project dir structure? If you have e.g. `Tests/` and then `Keywords/` and you run your tests, you have to do `Resources    ../Keywords/comon_resource_file`.

Comment: thank you both for taking the time to reply to me. I am using the Robot Framework plug in. It is from what i can see set up correctly and keywords are all recognised and working elsewhere. I have added the ../ and i think that has resolved the issue however i am now getting a completely different issue with the test case now not being recognised "[ ERROR ] Parsing 'Google\Tests\Google.Robot' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist."

Comment: ignore my previous comment i have now managed to make it work. Thank you for your help the ../ approach worked and all is now well. MAny thanks again

Comment: @Kem Please post how you have solved it as an answer. :)